# How do I get the querystring from a web page loaded in an Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview

For example if a WebView loaded "test.html?PageId=10", how would I get that PageId is equal to 10?

Answer (score 0):

Try `getUrl()` or `getOriginalUrl()` to get the URL, then parse the URL to find the page number.